# Animated Gif Image Not Working in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

'Now I am developing application in Phonegap framework.My question is animated images are displaying but there is no animation. In browser it is working fine.In emulator only displaying image. 
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
 private static class GIFView extends View{        
            Movie movie;  
            InputStream is=null;  
            long moviestart;  
            public GIFView(Context context) 
            {  
                super(context);  
                is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.smile);  
                movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);                 
            }  

            @Override  
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
            {  
                super.onDraw(canvas);  

                long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  

                 if (moviestart == 0) {   // first time  
                     moviestart = now;  
                 }            
                   int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;                 
                     movie.setTime(relTime);
                     movie.draw(canvas,100,100); 

                     this.invalidate();  
            }                         
        }
```

use this class and add the view to your layout,

```
 GIFView view=new GIFView(this);

            linear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
            linear.addView(view);
```

it may helps you..

Comment: hi.thanq..for your response, but im using phonegap framework,(only html pages are working).im executing html in browser it's working,but not in emulator

Comment: Hey, same issue, But solution is not given for phonegap!